# Преобразование типа переменной

Tags: c#

Совсем недавно стал изучать C#

Почему этот код неправильный?

```
int num = 4;
num = num.ToString();
```

Неужели всегда нужно создавать новую переменную, как в примере ниже?

```
int num = 4;
string str = num.ToString();
```

Comment: `C#` - язык со строгой типизацией, поэтому переменная в нём может иметь только один тип за время её жизни в области видимости. Хотите гибкую типизацию (и присущие ей грабли) - берите `Python`. А так да, под другой тип нужно описывать другую переменную. И для промышленной разработки это отлично. Меньше таких сюрпризов, когда вы думаете, что у вас в переменной что-то одно лежит, а там оказывается совсем другое.

Comment: спасибо.
да, я именно поэтому и спросил, перешел сюда из питона и немного смутило отсутствие такой записи кода :/
мне, как бывшему питонщику, режет глаз объявления стольких переменных

Comment: Ну так то это не очень хороший стиль использовать одну переменную для разных сущностей. Да, использование одной и той же переменной экономит память (если у вас линейная программа без функций, а если всё внутри функций делается, то разницы нет, переменные утилизируются по выходе из функций). Но это сильно запутывает того, кто читает программу и потенциально приводит к ошибкам.

Comment: Да, написал несколько утилит на Руби и понял, что в программах большего размера отсуствие типизации переменных будет проблемой.

Comment: @XenNon вам должно резать глаз использование одной переменной для разных данных. Если язык такое разрешает, то не значит, что так нужно делать.

Comment: У разных людей разный склад ума. Например, мне очевидно, что в маленький карман я могу положить маленький предмет, а большой предмет не влезет. В карман одежды я могу положить твёрдый предмет, а жидкость туда наливать не стоит - протечёт. Аналогично, мне очевидно, что разные объекты в памяти компьютера занимают разную память. Так что мой выбор: строгая статическая типизация. / А другие люди мыслят более абстрактно: для них память компьютера - универсальное хранилище чего угодно, как угодно. Их выбор:  ̶б̶ы̶т̶ь̶ ̶г̶о̶н̶и̶м̶ы̶м̶и̶ ̶и̶ ̶н̶а̶с̶м̶е̶х̶а̶е̶м̶ы̶м̶и̶ динамическая типизация.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В C# всё имеет тип. Типы могут наследоваться друг от друга, самый старший тип, от которого логически наследуются все остальные типы - это `object`.

C# имеет строгую типизацию. Чтобы задать переменную или объявить член класса, нужно определить её тип. Тип задается при объявлении переменной и далее не изменяется.

Можно ли использовать тот самой тип `object` для того что вы хотите сделать? Можно.

```
object num = 4;
num = num.ToString();
```

Но так никто не делает, потому что далее работать с переменной `num` неудобно. Например нельзя сделать так.

```
object num = 4;
num = num + 1; // ошибка: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'
```

Дополнительно к этим проблемам добавляется то что `object` - это ссылочный тип, а `int` - значимый, компилятор создаст обертку вокруг `int` (boxing) и код получится неоптимальный. Поэтому следует использовать явные конкретные типы, так будет работать быстрее.

Кстати для значимых типов вроде `int` при присваивании не выделяется память на безусловной основе. Скорей всего после компиляции переменная будет жить только в регистре процессора или же место под её хранения будет выделено в стеке, это происходит очень быстро и не требует последующей сборки мусора.

Другими словами, не стоит переживать, что вы создаете новые переменные. Компилятор очень умный, вот вам пример:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
int c = a + b;
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Как вы думаете, что получится, если этот код скомпилировать, а потом декомпилировать? А вот что:

```
Console.WriteLine(7);
```

А вот из этого кода

```
string hello = "Hello";
string hello = "World";
Console.WriteLine(hello + " " + world);
```

Получится

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
```

То есть компилятор, оптимизируя код, сам понял при сборке приложения что вы больше нигде и никак не изменяете переменные, и он сам воспринял их как константы и провел необходимые оптимизации ещё до компиляции.

Конечно, при отладке никаких таких оптимизаций не будет, чтобы не помешать вам пошагово отлаживать код. А вот в релизной (Release) сборке она будет, за это отвечает галочка "Оптимизировать код" в настройках профиля сборки.

Поэтому пока не заморачивайтесь сильно о расходах ресурсов, учитесь писать код, корректно выполняющий поставленные задачи, а компилятор позаботится об остальном. С опытом вы научитесь контролировать аллокации (создание `new` объектов), память и писать мощные оптимизации. Но сейчас такие знания могут лишь создать много сложных и ненужных новичку вопросов. Хотя, если вам очень интересно, почитайте про Сборщик мусора (Garbage Collector) и про CLR в целом (Common Language Runtime), там всё про работу с памятью расписано.

---

Кстати, тип `string` является ссылочным и неизменяемым. То есть однажды созданная строка уже не может быть изменена в будущем, а конкатенация и прочие операции со строками приводят к выбрасыванию ранее созданных строк и созданию новых.

```
string hello = "Hello";
string world = hello; // обе ссылки указывают на один и тот же объект
Console.WriteLine(hello.ReferenceEquals(world)); // True
world = hello + " World";
Console.WriteLine(hello) // "Hello"
```

Это потому что была создана новая строка и ссылка на нее была помещена в переменную `world`. А если бы строка была изменяемым типом, вывод был бы другой. В этом есть свои плюсы и минусы, плюсы в том что если откуда-то вам пришла строка, то есть гарантия, что в каком-то другом потоке ее никто не изменит (многопоточность). А минусы - выделение памяти каждый раз когда надо строку изменить, но это можно объехать, для этого существуют специальные классы, например `StringBuilder` или методы для быстрого создания строк с известной длиной типа `string.Create`. Вот такие вот фокусы.

Comment: А ещё есть интернирование строк, раз уж в хитрости лезть ))

Comment: В c# много мути. String - это ссылочный тип, но неизменяемый. А вот узнать программо, что это неизменяемый тип - нельзя. Не так ли?

Comment: @rotabor Надеюсь, под чужими ответами с вами общаться разрешено? Итак - в чём же "муть" `C#`? Строки в высокоуровневых языках обычно ссылочный не изменяемый тип, это нормально и логично. Узнать про неизменяемость вроде и правда нельзя простым способом, это действительно нелогично, хорошо бы было наследование какое-то, намекающее на иммутабельность. Хотя может я просто забыл.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да в других языках особо и не выделяют, что строки по сути неизменяемые, как и массивы. Любой программист понимает, что чтобы удлиннить строку, нужно иметь под это место в памяти. И чего с этим так носиться? А в других языках, например, можно изменить содержимое строки. И если это её не удлинняет, то выделения памяти под новое значение не будет. И ничего плохого в этом нет.

Comment: @CrazyElf общаться можно, но без фантазий.

Comment: @rotabor _А вот узнать программо, что это неизменяемый тип - нельзя. Не так ли?_ этому учат всех новичнов на хэлловорлдных курсах и в туториалах. В каждом языке, в каждой среде разработки есть свои приколы, и их надо просто изучать. Неизменяемые строки это не "муть" и даже не близко. Чтобы согласиться с этим, достаточно просто понять причину, почему они получились именно такие. Можно начать с того, а вообще зачем придумали и используют немутабельные типы? Да еще и вводят новые немутабельные сущности, `record` например. С ума посходили? )))

Comment: @aepot спасибо, ваш ответ очень полезен и интересен к прочтению)

Comment: @XenNon кстати, в C# таки существует динамическая типизация и за нее отвечает специальный мета-тип `dynamic`. Но он медленный и прожорливый, так как там кругом обертки в обертках. О существовании его знать надо, а вот использовать не стоит. Для меня до сих пор загадка, зачем оно появилось, без этого можно было жить прекрасно. Хотя всей истории C# я не знаю, может это просто рудимент.

Comment: @aepot 1. Вы тоже любитель подискутировать со своимим фантазиями? 2. У мень "муть", у вас "прикол" - об одном и том же, но разными словами. В эти приколы я отнёс бы базове типы, для которых в c# сделали поддерживаемые компилятором объектные обёртки. Это хорошо с точки зрения использования в программах. И об этом действительно нужно знать. И думать надо.

Comment: dynamic, в основном, предназначен для поддержки COM. Об этом написано в документации. Чтобы на этапе выполнения применять к нему любые методы и свойства, о которых не было известно во время компиляции.

Comment: @rotabor я слишком старый для фантазий, у меня только ностальгия и воспоминания. Про COM+dynamic не вникал, но сейчас для этого есть интерфейсы и GUID контракты с маршаллингом. Видимо точно было полезно когда-то, но устарело.

Comment: dynamic может быть полезен для реализации двойной диспетчеризации, например, в паттерне Посетитель (Visitor). Без него кода получается существенно больше. / Ну и планировалось широкое использование динамических языков типа IronPython, IronRuby в связке с C#. Не взлетело. @rotabor

Comment: _узнать программно, что это неизменяемый тип_ - рефлексией посмотреть члены типа. Если имеются только геттеры и ничего больше - то тип иммутабельный. Но это неточно. В геттер тоже можно впихнуть код меняющий внутреннее состояние объекта. Да и на этапе создания можно передать в конструктор ссылку на объект, через который потом менять состояние. М-м-м... Похоже, да, по-простому это не определить. @rotabor

Answer (score 0):

Почему этот код неправильный? Потому, что переменная num объявлена как переменная типа int, и она не помет принять значение num.ToString() типа string.

Неужели всегда нужно создавать новую переменную, как в примере ниже? Невсегда. Если нужно сохранять значения такого же типа, то можно новую и не создавать. Но это может быть не очень хорошо с точки зрения понимания кода.

Вообще, экономить на именах переменных нет никакой выгоды - сейчас даже не нужно печатать текст программы на бумаге. Имена переменных важны только для компилятора в подавляющем большинстве случаев. Так что нет никаких причин не создавать новые переменные, когда они нужны. Имеет смысл только информация, которая в них хранится.

Нужно учитывать, что в c#, как и в большинстве языков, объявление новой переменной влечёт за собой выделение памяти. (Это можно проигнорировать: "Не знаю, как в Питоне, а в Руби появление новой переменной далеко не всегда означает выделение памяти. Память выделяется только под объект, а переменных для этого объекта в программе можно насоздавать сколько угодно, и они будут всего лишь псевдонимами друг друга." Дальше дообсуждались до того, что память выделяется, хоть и под таблицу переменных, но разницы, по сути, нет.)

Нельзя не добавить, что есть тип object, и ему можно присваивать любые значения:

```
object num = 4;
num = num.ToString();
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146817/discussion-on-answer-by-rotabor---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.